# How to install xampp in mac

Tags: macos, xampp

I am using MacBook Air. I installed the xampp but it's not working.

After some research, I found the URL http://localhost:8080/dashboard/ and I am getting the xampp. Now I am confused where should I get htdocs folder to add my code. Can anyone assist me?

[image]

Let's talk about in details

I downloaded the xampp from this link https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

and I move it on the application. Now I am getting the xampp icon in application.

[image]

Then I open the xampp and I got a popup like and I click on start
[image]

[image]

I enable the 8080 port number.

[image]

Then I just I checked in the browser http://localhost:8080/dashboard/ and I found the xampp dashboard page.
Now I am not getting the htdocs folder. would you help me out in this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I too have had lots of confusion setting up XAMPP on my Mac. 
Things the docs said would work, just plain did not.

The short answer to your question: In MacOS X the htdocs dir of the virtual server is in:

`/Users/<YOUR-USER-NAME>/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs`

---

More complete instructions for getting the server up:

1. Open up the XAMPP Application
2. Under General/Services start the XAMPP services
3. Under Network make sure to enable a port config (I chose localhost:8080->80)
4. In the Volumes "tab" click "Mount" beside `/opt/lampp` and then you can click "Explore" to open a finder window to the virtual server.

   - This will cause the virtual Network-Drive 192.168.xxx.yyy to show up in the Finder sidebar which has a single folder named `lampp`
   - Additionally a new external drive named `lampp` will also be available in Finder.
5. However you get to lampp, put your source-files in the `htdocs` folder.

---

Links that DID work for me on first launching:

- http://localhost:8080/dashboard/
- http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/
- http://192.168.64.2/dashboard/

Links that did NOT work, in spite of docs claiming otherwise:

- http://localhost/ or http://localhost/index.php
- http://192.168.64.2/phpmyadmin/ <--Access Forbidden 403

Comment: Give me some time to check your answer.

Comment: I tried all the steps, I got a htdocs folder. first I was trying http://localhost/test/test1.php then it's was getting the "Unable to connect" then I tried http://localhost:8080/test/test1.php then it's working. Thanks for the help. It's working for me. After 3 months I got a solution.

Answer (score 5):

A little late to the thread but I hit and solved this issue and I believe the OP had downloaded and installed the wrong version. At the time I am writing this, the link on the [downloads page](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) is for `.dmg` file is a VM file, or at least missing features of the full download. Instead of downloading that, go to the `more downloads` section

[image]

Once there, choose the version you need for your OS. This, and some `mysql` tweaks that are answered in multiple connected topics got me running.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your XAMPP is working fine. You have to use Finder to go to htdocs.

Follow these steps -

1. Open the XAMPP application and hit "Start" button.
2. Make sure everything is proper by hitting "Go to Application".
3. Now you should see the dashboard on your browser, if not, restart the application and try again.
4. Go to Finder and on the sidebar you should see a volume labeled "192.168.64.2", go there and you will find a folder named "lamp".
   [See under the locations section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTlx7.png)
5. Inside lamp there will be htdocs, where you can place all the files you want the browser to access.[Click on lamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qsg9.png)

Comment: I tried,1) Open the xampp in finder 2) Clicked on start 3) apache start 4) 8080 enable. (All the images are available in the question) And I clicked on "Go to Application " browser open And I got "safari can't connect to the server". I tried 4-5 times still same issue

Comment: I disabled it but same issue.

Comment: If the above doesn't work check permissions of the htdocs folder.

Comment: I tried your address and I got "unable to connect" https://prnt.sc/lydvmf   I am not getting htdocs folder in my application

Comment: Please check my finder screenshot https://prnt.sc/lydxit I am getting the only xampp and when I clicked on it then it's asking for a start

Comment: @user9437856 did you get the dashboard screen previously? If yes, then your XAMPP is working fine. To get htdocs folder follow the step 4.

Comment: Yeah you have to click "Start" once you open the XAMPP and the start all the services.

Comment: Yes, now go to the application is working and address is http://192.168.64.2/dashboard/  . now where i will get htdocs folder?  I am not getting volume labeled  option

Comment: Now go to Finder and follow 4th step.

Comment: Which option are you talking about in the screenshot https://prnt.sc/lye2hp